# Bind Objects To DataGridview and Reorder Column

Tags: linq, c#-4.0, data-binding, datagridview

I want to bind the object list to dataGridView.
Now i want the desired column to be the way i definde them. i.e., I want the objects to be order the way i want.
Like

```
var dataSource = linkItemListCommon.Select(x => new DataToBind { Select = x.Default, FileName = x.Text, CurrentDate = x.Date+" "+x.Time , PreviousDate = string.Empty, Size = x.Size }).ToList();

var filenamesList = new BindingList<DataToBind>(dataSource);
            dgvDownLoadMaster.DataSource = filenamesList;
```

I want the datagrid columns to be in the order that i define.
Like here i expect them to be in order given below:

Select FileName CurrentDate PreviousDate Size

But the column list is appearing not as per my requirements.
How to Do that.Please help.

Comment: Anyone kindly reply to my question. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create columns by hand and then you can order them easily. You can add columns trough designer  and just set each column `DataPropertyName` to corresponding field.

Or you can create each column programmatically:

```
var col = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
col.DataPropertyName = "Select ";
col.HeaderText = "Select";
col.Name = "ColSelect";

dgvDownLoadMaster.Columns.Add(col);
```

you have to do this for each column and do it before `databinding`.

Comment: This is working but i am getting extra column FileName after binding.

Comment: add `dgvDownLoadMaster.AutoGenerateColumns = false;` before binding :)

Comment: @ gzaxx This will not add column but my column with Filename data is not getting binded to the gridview.

Comment: Can you show your updated code, how are you adding columns? Because probably you forgot to add 1 column or to set proper `DataPropertyName `

Comment: @ gzaxx Just one more question can we reorder column on drag drop..Please guide me how that can be implemented.

Comment: Simple setting `dgvDownLoadMaster.AllowUserToOrderColumns = true;` should do the job, otherwise just look [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/d081d7bd-014d-4e50-90a2-556568e38bcf/datagridview-column-reordering-via-drag-n-drop) good luck!